# Why does the URL change when I create a route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 project, and in a view, I have a link like this...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Partner", "Home", new {id = Model.PartnerID})">
  ...loads of markup here...
</a>
```

This works fine, and gives me an URL of the form `/Home/Partner/100`

However, if I add a route for the action...

```
routes.MapRoute("Partner", "Partner", new { controller = "Home", action = "Partner" });
```

...then the URL is rendered as `/Partner?id=100`

Is there a way to get an URL of the form `/Partner/100`?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your desired map route like following.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Partner", 
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Partner", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  
 );
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it looks like you just beat @StephenMuecke to it

Answer (score 1):

Your route definition needs to include a segment for the `id`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Partner",
    url: "Partner/{id}",
    defaults: { controller = "Home", action = "Partner" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked @hsnbl's as the answer as that came in just before yours, even though they were both equally good

Comment: Seriously? You asked how to generate `../Partner/100` which my answer does and then you accept an answer which does not

Comment: It did for me. If it hadn't worked, I wouldn't have accepted it as the answer.

Comment: That answer will **NOT** generate `. /Partner/100`. It's just exacrly the same as the default route and can only generate `../Home/Partner/100`. Clearly you have not even tested your code.

Answer (score -1):

you can put the entry in the Global.asax.cs like below:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "customroute1",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "partner",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );



routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

}

**Note :** The order you place the code in the global.ascx file is very important.

**[Additional Official Info:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)**

When you create a new ASP.NET MVC application, the application is already configured to use ASP.NET Routing. ASP.NET Routing is setup in two places.
First, ASP.NET Routing is enabled in your application's Web configuration file (Web.config file).

There are four sections in the configuration file that are relevant to routing: the system.web.httpModules section, the system.web.httpHandlers section, the system.webserver.modules section, and the system.webserver.handlers section. Be careful not to delete these sections because without these sections routing will no longer work.

Second, and more importantly, a route table is created in the application's Global.asax file. The Global.asax file is a special file that contains event handlers for ASP.NET application lifecycle events. The route table is created during the Application Start event.